# Embedding CKEditor in SWT Java application in Linux

Tags: java, swt, ckeditor

I'm having a problem with CKEditor not functioning properly. I have an SWT Java app running in Ubuntu. The app uses a Browser object to display an HTML page in the project which does nothing but display a CKEditor instance.

If I open the HTML page **in Firefox**, CKEditor renders OK, and everything works.

If I run my Java app **through Eclipse**, the widget displays the HTML page, CKEditor renders OK, and everything works.

If I package my application up **into a jar file** and then run the app, the widget displays the HTML page, CKEditor renders OK, but nothing works. I can't type in the text area, none of the toolbar buttons work, and the javascript I have which runs

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( e ) { e.editor.execCommand('maximize'); });
```

does not execute.

I suspect something is wrong with the way the relative paths work when the files are packaged inside the jar, but everything appears to load correctly - the toolbar images, stylesheet, etc all load, but then no buttons can be clicked. It's like the UI breaks.

The only button which responds at all is if I click "Source", in which case I **can** edit the text area; clicking "Source" a second time goes back to WYSIWYG mode and leaves the CKEditor toolbar disabled (greyed out; no icons can be clicked on).

I have no ideas left for what to try. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand: do your HTML files get bundled in the JAR file?

In any case, I would recommend proxying the files from an embedded web server. The [DJ Native Swing project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns) and [DJ Sweet project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet) have several HTML editors (including CKEditor) implemented using the SWT Browser and they all use this technique.